# power for estimating treatment heterogeneity in RCT

Tags: interaction, statistical-power, clinical-trials, heterogeneity

Could someone point me to a good resource for estimating power for detecting treatment heterogeneity via interactions in MR?

Let's assume that individuals will be randomized to two study arms. To estimate heterogeneity (moderation), we would regress the continuous outcome on an indicator of assignment to treatment (0/1), a pre-treatment covariate (dichotomous or continuous), an interaction of the two, and possibly a vector of other baseline covariates, study strata, etc.

I've read 'rules of thumb' about sample sizes for moderation needing to be 4x as large as the sample required to detect a certain main effect. Looking to estimate more precisely.